# Extract Data Definitions for Indexes from PostgreSQL using `pg_index` table

Tags: postgresql, indexing, pg-catalog

I'm trying to extract data definitions from a PostgreSQL database for indexes into the application.

The structure in my application, currently, looks something like this:

```js
type IndexColExpr = {
  col_or_expr: string;
};
type IncludeColumn = {
  name: string;
};
type Index = {
  id: number;
  table_id: number;
  table_name: string;
  name: string;
  unique: boolean;
  method: string;
  columns: IndexColExpr[];
  include_columns: IncludeColumn[];
  where: string;
};
```

I'm using the `pg_class` and `pg_index` to get the information that I need.

So far everything is going well until I get to the part where the index is on expressions (not a simple column name). Those expressions are stored in `pg_index.indexprs` which is of the type `pg_node_tree`.

The problem is when there are multiple expressions in the index; they will all be encoded inside the `indexprs` column as a single `pg_node_tree` value and I need them separated. That means I have to parse `pg_node_tree` to get individual expressions. Or I can convert `pg_node_tree` to SQL string using `pg_get_expr()`, but I still have to parse the SQL DDL script. Since they are in a *list* format `(expr1, expr2)` I can't simply cast to `text[]`. Both `pg_node_tree` and the DDL script can contain arbitrary expressions, so I can't use a simple split-by-comma to get them.

Is there something in PostgreSQL that will allow me to extract individual expressions without parsing `pg_node_tree` or the DDL script?

If there isn't, then maybe I shouldn't bother with `pg_index` and just parse the `CREATE INDEX` query provided by `pg_get_indexdef()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two overloaded variants of [**`pg_get_indexdef()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE):

1. If you only pass the OID of the index, you get the complete reconstructed `CREATE INDEX` DDL script.
2. But if you **also** pass the `smallint` number of the index expression ( = `pg_attribute.attnum`) *and* a `boolean` "pretty" flag, you get the definition of that index column. As the manual puts it:

   > If column is supplied and is not zero, only the definition of that column is reconstructed.

To get all index columns of a given index separately, and in order (plain column references and expressions alike):

```sql
SELECT pg_get_indexdef(a.attrelid, a.attnum, true)
FROM   pg_attribute a
WHERE  a.attrelid = 'my_index'::regclass  -- your index name here
ORDER  BY a.attnum;
```

I am going to `pg_attribute` directly, we don't need to involve `pg_index` for this. If you need the connection:

```
pg_index.indexrelid = pg_attribute.attrelid
```

If there can be ambiguity, schema-qualify the index name:

```
'my_schema.my_index'::regclass
```

This does *not* include any decorators per index column like `DESC NULLS LAST`, operator class, collation, ... Those are encoded separately in `indoption`, `indclass`, `indcollation` of the table `pg_index`.